# asp.net model class pulling data from a table with join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am not an expert in .NET. So please excuse if this is a silly question.

I am working on a webapi written in .NET core 2.0 MVC using Entity Framework. I have a user class and user has many roles. So one of the role is Member.

I have a member class in Models. How can I get a list of all the Members.

Technically if I do dbContext.members.all(), it should run

```
select * from users u inner join user_roles r on u.id = r.user_id
```

Is this doable?

One of the thing which I am currently doing:

Anytime I delete a record, i put deletedAt timestamp for that record and I have a default query filter which will ignore these records when making a query from a controller. e.g. _context.users.all() will ignore all the users who have a deletedAt timestamp. and I have achived it using the following code:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(x => EF.Property<DateTime?>(x, "deletedAt") == null);
```

I would like to do something like this to the problem mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using sql or linq?, or do you want to use the linq of the sql in your question?

Comment: Any of those two are OK. but when I will be using Member model in other parts of the app, i will be using linq

Comment: The easiest way is to have a table that links both the users and the roles and then using linq to query that table. example if the link table is `UserRoles`, then when you use `var members = dbContext.UserRoles.Where(m => m.Role.Name == "Members")"`